# Deserialize query string to querydict (sent by AJAX)

Tags: ajax, django

Maybe it's a problem of bad serializing on my part, but I have problems to deserialize my data:

I'm sending a Modelform via AJAX (by POST) to a view. There's is no error but the ModelForm saved creates an empty item in my model.

I've checked the debugger for `request.POST`: There is the key corresponding to what was sent by AJAX but it's not a QueryDict but a String of the form:

`request.POST['keyinrequestpost'] = 'csrfmiddlewaretoken=pA.....zutQ&FirstField=BlaBlad&SecondField=BlaBla&ThirdField=BlaBla'`

Apparently, doing then:

`MyModelForm(request.POST['keyinrequestpost'])`

is not working (the item created got only empty field) since it's not a QueryDict?
I thought the conversion was automatic??

How can I deserialize this to get a QueryDict usable by MyModelForm() ?

my AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#newword_form').bind('submit', function(e){
    var newword_form = $('#newword_form')
    newword_form_serialized = newword_form.serialize();
    $.ajax({url: '/create_newword/', 
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data:{csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}', 
                'newword': newword_form_serialized } , 
            success: function(data){ 
            ...
```

and my view:

```
if 'newword' in request.POST.keys(): # the form has been posted
        f = MyModelForm(request.POST['newword'])
        if f.is_valid():
            word = f.save() 
            return render(request, ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to send the `csrf_token` this way. If it's inside your form; **that's where it should be**, then you can simply serialize the form and send it in data.

Upon serializing, the **csrf token** and all the **form data** will be included in a dictionary and sent to the server. You can then simply access it inside your views.

Try this(JavaScript):

```
//var url = your url;
$.ajax({
        url : url,
        type : 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $('form#newword_form').serialize(),
        success : function(data, status, xhr){
             //success
        },
        error : function(data , status , xhr){
            //error
        }
});
```

Then in you views.py:

```
f = MyModelForm(request.POST)
```

will work just fine.

Tell me if it doesn't.

**Additional notes:** I hope your html looks somewhat like this:

```
<form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <h4>Form Title</h4>
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: wonderful answer! Thanks a lot for your time. And the 'error' part in Ajax helped me a lot for further problems.